# Rolling back an APK install to a previous version

Tags: samsung, installation, apk, uninstallation

I have been using APKMirror update which helps me see if any app updates are available.
I had it connected to only check Google Play which worked great for a long time

My problem is that there was an update flagged for Samsung Internet and when I downloaded it, I realised that it had downloaded from `Aptoide` and it had installed a foreign version of the app. (I think it may be chinese but not 100% sure)

I uninstalled the app, and then downloaded the current version from Galaxy Store, which was a slightly older version that Aptoid provided

However, all it done was reinstall the Aptoid version. I tried using Google play and had the same issue.

I then went to APK Mirror and downloaded the version that is available from Google play and Galaxy store, so that I could install manually.

I get an error telling me `App not installed as package appears to be invalid`

But the reason for this appears to be found when I try and install using `APK Mirror Installer`

I get an error `App Installation Failed, The new package has an older version code than the currently installed package`

I have uninstalled the app but there appears to still be remnants of the app on the phone which is making it difficult to revert.

Are there any recommended steps to take to rectify this issue?

Comment: Web browser app can be set as WebView provider (provide web browser view to other apps). May be Samsung Internet app was configured as WebView provider and thus is used by other apps. After uninstalling it reboot your phone. You can see selected WebView provider in the Android Developer menu (hidden by default).

Comment: Can you not install an archived version from github

Comment: @Archerbob it wont let me because it is telling me (as per the question) that the version I am installing is older than the current version

Comment: @Robert I have the Developer Options enabled, however, The only Webview option I can see is `Webview implementation` which only has one entry - `Android System Webview 106.0.5249.126`

Comment: I usually try SDMaid for the "CorpseFinder" option, to see if remnants found can be deleted.

Comment: @wbogacz tried the `CorpseFinder` didnt work either :(

Comment: @wbogacz The app doesnt seem to uninstall.. I used `appcontrol` within SD Maid and the app is still showing, I uninstalled from there but it keeps coming back only difference is there is an orange box saying `Stopped`

Comment: Would a factory reset remove the offending app and all traces, then install the version you want.  Remember to backup any important files first.